# Как быстро перемножить 2 матрицы на динамических c-массивах?

Tags: c++, массивы, математика, матрицы

Как быстро перемножить 2 матрицы на динамических c-массивах?

Comment: Совершенно некорректный вопрос. Скорость перемножения зависит от ряда факторов: размер матрицы, природа её элементов (в том числе их размер), способ считывания, хранения, кольцо, в котором производятся вычисления - вот лишь часть вопросов, на которые нужно ответить в первую очередь.

Comment: @Zealint нужен алгоритм хотя бы квадратный всё остальное стандартно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартной формуле используются "симметричные" индексы:

```
a[i][k] * b[k][j]
    ^^^----^^^
 ^^^----------^^^
```

Можно получить улучшение производительности, если транспонировать вторую матрицу:

```
a[i][k] * b[j][k]
    ^^^-------^^^
 ^^^-------^^^
```

Теперь в обоих рядах данные лежат подряд, можно сохранить указатель, что уберёт лишнее разыменование, а также данные смогут нормально попадать в кэш процессора.

---

Если матрицы достаточно крупные, то имеет смысл подумать о асимптотически более быстрых алгоритмах, например, Карацубы.

Comment: @nikita, транспонирование квадратично, а в перемножении - куб. Я про inpace-инвертирование. Если там ещё выделение памяти будет, то уже непонятно. В общем, лучше замерить. Но если есть вариант сразу считать транспонированную матрицу и это ничего не портит, то им стоит воспользоваться. А вообще, можно замерить. А ещё я назвал транспонирование инвертированием...

Comment: какой указатель можно сохранить?

Comment: @nikita, `a[i]` и `b[j]`. Думаю, компилятор сам догадается.

Comment: Эксперимент показал, что практически ничего при реальных размерах - 100x100 - транспонирование не дает... Выигрыш примерно 5% - никак не компенсирует **долгого** и старательного транспонирования матрицы.

Comment: @Harry, [5%](http://ideone.com/Xguh2O) на n=100, [15%](http://ideone.com/Drj4k3) на n=200, [30%](http://ideone.com/Uposm6) на n=500. А вот попытка сохранить указатель самому ничего не даёт - компилятор и сам умный: http://ideone.com/QoW7x9 Если неверно замерил, поправь.

Comment: Если уж решили заниматься подобными сравнениями, то рекомендую сначала ознакомиться с результатами моего [конкурса](http://zealint.ru/science/fast-matrix-multiplication-comp.html), что я проводил лет 6 назад.

Answer (score 3):

Быстрее всего - обычным умножением матриц.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классическая формула -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всякие "ускоренные" алгоритмы типа Штрассена - для обычных задач смысла не имеют...

Comment: Смысл имеет одну матрицу инвертировать, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Для большей локализации кеша? в принципе да, но при реальных размерах обычно матрицы в кеше помещаются. Впрочем, надо поиграться как-нибудь...

Comment: Не только. Мы ещё разыменование указателя экономим. Я вроде в ответе написал?

Comment: Это же динамическая память - вообще нет гарантий, что соседние строки там рядом лежат.

Comment: Ну если человек настолько дурак, чтоб выделять память не одним куском - то кто ж ему доктор?...

Answer (score 0):

"Быстрее всего" - взять специализированную библиотеку типа MKL, ATLAS, Vienna CL и подобных. Во-первых, в них реализован BLAS - а это джентельменский набор по работе с матрицами, во-вторых, он *действительно* хорошо оптимизирован - (а у ViennaCL - работает на GPU), что позволяет ему работать быстрее наивной реализации.